# Kind of soap to use in shower?

Tags: greywater

I used my shower water to water my plants. What is the best soap to use, that will not harm the plants ?

Comment: Why are you watering plants with used water?  If you wouldn't drink the water you shouldn't be watering plants with that water.  Tap water is the worst and to add soap...ugh.  Are you watering potted plants or your garden?  Garden is more tolerant.  Potted plants deserve bottled waters...always the best as they do not have the protection plants in the out of doors have.

Comment: @stormy we don't know where the OP is, and how easy/cheap it is to get drinking water.  And by saying "tap water is the worst" you're contradicting yourself unless you expect the OP to buy bottled water.

Comment: @ChrisH  That was exactly my point, perhaps I didn't communicate very well, but tap water should not even be drunk by animals.  Fluoride is major poison and they even put this stuff in bottled water.  Not at all for teeth!  I drink well water but always bought bottled water and have had a tough time to find water without fluoride.

Answer (score 1):

Very diluted shower water, or change the soap to soft soap, or perhaps baby soap? although generally not a good idea unless in drought conditions and only done for short periods.